# Retrieving Weave routing information

Tags: networking, routing, docker, weave

I am using [Weave Net](https://www.weave.works/documentation/net-latest-introducing-weave/) to connect my Docker containers across different hosts. Weave is making use of "Fast Datapath" which handles the routing in Kernel Space (inside the [OVS (Open vSwitch)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/openvswitch.txt) Module as shown in the diagram below.)

[image: weave routing]

In oder to get a better understanding about how Weave routes traffic, I would like to see the routing entries of the OVS Module. There are commands like `ovs-vsctl show` which "prints a brief overview of the database contents" but this didn't work. Seems like Weave is running its own OVS instance which cannot be accessed with this command.

I also tried inspecting Weave with the

```
weave status        [targets | connections | peers | dns | ipam]
```

commands but that didn't show any detailed routing information either.

**So, does anyone know how to see the routing table that weave uses to decide where to route packets destined to a certain docker container?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see flows ("routes") which Weave Net installs into the datapath of `openvswitch` you can run `weave report`. The flows are listed under the `.Router.OverlayDiagnostics.fastdp.Flows` field.

> Seems like Weave is running its own OVS instance which cannot be
>   accessed with this command.

Yes, Weave Net does not use the OVS user space modules. It only relies on the `openvswitch` kernel module and friends (`vxlan`). See http://openvswitch.org/support/ovscon2016/8/0935-pumputis.pdf or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKN_oaRX8Vc for more details